# How to call a JQuery UI Modal with MVC (CRUD)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a Car View (List.cshtml) that shows my Car´s list... I´d like to add a button/link:
 **"Add car..."**

That button must open my View (Create.cshtml) in a JQuery Modal UI...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you go:

demo: http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/Meals/Index

download it from here: http://awesome.codeplex.com

**Create/Edit** in **jquery UI dialog** (popup)

delete with confirm dialog (ui dialog)

the list is just a simple table with a foreach

Comment: Thanks Omu...
I have one question, My Controllers are in a separated Project (from Views)...

So, when I tried to add that:
@Html.MakePopupForm<CarController>(o => o.Create()) 

I got that error : CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Paul I think that is because of cshtml, if you use <Generics> you must do @(Html.Act<Foo>(and so on))

Comment: Solved... But now I got other error : The partial view '~\Views\Shared\Awesome\PopupForm.ascx' was not found. The following locations were searched:
~\Views\Shared\Awesome\PopupForm.ascx...

But the PopupForm.ascx is in the right path... Any idea?

Comment: @Paul I've installed today the latest version of mvc3 and it works, the only difference for the razor is that I had to add the awesome namespaces in the views/web.config <system.web.webPages.razor> <pages><namespaces>