# Form of data returned by .get to allow .html to populate form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

Using jQuery/jQueryUI I want to populate a form using this HTML/JS show below.

The url  "editController/loadContents" will return some data and .html will (I believe) populate the form based upon the data but what structure should the data have ?.

The only examples I can find in the jQueryUI doco are for single element forms.

My guess is that some JSON which looks like this ...

```
{
     "starttime": "10:00",
     "endtime": "11:00",
 }
```

... would populate the input fields. But how are the OPTIONS for the SELECTs provided and one of the the OPTIONs specified as 'selected' ?

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <!-- loaded from ajax call -->
  <form id="exampleForm">
    <fieldset>
    <label for="activity">Activity</label>
    <br />
    <select name="activity" id="activity" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="subactivity">Sub-Activity</label>
    <br />
    <select name="subactivity" id="subactivity" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="activity">Reason</label>
    <br />
    <select name="reason" id="reason" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="starttime">Start</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="starttime" id="starttime" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <br />
    <label for="endtime">End</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="endtime" id="endtime" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" onclick="Save()" />
  </form>


</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
      $('.myPop').click(function() {
          $.get("editController/loadContents", function(data){
             $("#dialog").html(data);
           });           
          $("#dialog").dialog('open');
      });
  });


function Save(){
 $.post("/editController/Edit", $("#exampleForm").serialize(),
  function(data){
     $("#dialog").dialog('close');
    //update grid with ajax call
  });
}

</script>
```

BTW I've adapted this code from the very useful answer at [How to use a jQuery UI Modal Form from ASP.Net MVC list page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516674/how-to-use-a-jquery-ui-modal-form-from-asp-net-mvc-list-page/1518429#1518429)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .html will (I believe) populate the
>   form based upon the data but what
>   structure should the data have ?.

`.html()` simply sets the HTML content of the matched elements in your jQuery selector to the contents you provide. There's no automatic setting of values for existing inputs based on a JSON object.

This leaves you with two options:

1. Make your server-side code return a populated HTML form that you blindly use `.html()` with, or
2. Write JavaScript to associate the raw data you get back from the server with the `input`s that exist on your page.

> But how are the OPTIONS for the
>   SELECTs provided and one of the the
>   OPTIONs specified as 'selected' ?

To dynamically insert options into an existing `select` element, you could simply generate a new `option` element and `.append()` it:

```
$("<option>")
    .text("Swimming")
    .attr("selected", true) // Set the option's "selected" attribute
    .attr("value", 1)
    .appendTo("#activity");
```

Obviously, you would have to adapt that code to the JSON data you get back from your server-side code, probably looping through an array of activities you got back and creating a new `option` for each one.

Comment: Thanks very much for the very useful answer - I had higher aspirations for the humble .html than were justified !