# Modal form to edit row in a grid (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

For many days I've been trying unsuccessfully to implement Modal dialog editing in a flexigrid.

I started with a very simple example:

http://mvc4beginner.com/Sample-Code/Insert-Update-Delete/Asp-.Net-MVC-Ajax-Insert-Update-Delete-Using-Flexigrid.html

I expanded this example a lot, but I hit a road block and I don't know how to achieve desired functionality.

I implemented the following jquery function:

```
    function RunModalDialog(title, url)
    {
        $("#sform").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            resizable: true,
            width: 1200,
            height: 750,
            minHeight: 600,
            minWidth:950
        });
        if (title)
            $("#sform").dialog("option", "title", title);

        if (url)
            $("#sform").load(url).dialog("open");
        else
          $("#sform").dialog("open");
```

And I am calling it from Add button (without url) and from the Edit button (with a url).

It works OK for the Add (although I haven't yet implemented actual save and grid refresh), but I can not make it work on Edit.

Here is my main view code

```
@model CardNumbers.Objects.Client

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Clients";
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Clients.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
}

<form id="frmClientsSearch">
    <label for="clientNo">Client No: </label>
    <input type="number" name="searchClientNo" class="numericOnly" /><br />
    <label for="clientName">Client Name: </label>
    <input type="text" size="25" value="Please enter the search value" class="SelectOnEntry"
        name="searchClientName" />

    <input type="button" id="btnClientsSearch" value="Find / Refresh" />
</form>
<div style="padding-left: 150px; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;" id="ClientsResults">
    <table id="flexClients" style="display: none">
    </table>
</div>

<div id="editor" style ="visibility :hidden ">
      @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sform", title = "Client Info" }))
     { 
        @Html.Partial("_ClientForm", Model)   
      }      
</div>
```

And the Edit method of the client controller returns a view which is

```
    @model CardNumbers.Objects.Client

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit Client";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PopupLayout.cshtml";
    }

    @Html.Partial("_ClientForm", Model)

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        
    }
```

I originally had the BeginForm inside the _ClientForm and I could see the form, but the x (close) and Resize didn't work. I now tried moving the line that starts the form outside, but now the behavior is even worse.

Can you tell me how this is supposed to work?

Comment: When you do the edit, is the content from the URL loaded into #sform? Kinda need to tell where you are having trouble

Comment: I am going to add more content into my question to provide my main view code and the Edit method of the controller. Please check my question again in a few minutes

Comment: Is there a way to add images of the behavior I am seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can think of doing is

1. Check that the URL is valid,
2. Call dialog once the div has been filled up

   `$("#sform").load(url).dialog("open");`

becomes

```
    $("#sform").load(url, function(){
       $("#sform").dialog("open");
    });
```

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

NOTE THIS WAS A PROPOSED ANSWER TO THE QUESTION BEFORE IT WAS MODIFIED

Comment: I think being a beginner I still don't exactly understand how all of this is supposed to work. I wish I can insert a picture with the error I got when I changed my code using your suggestions

Comment: The error is now Unhandled exception at line 2, column 13143 in http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js

0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Comment: THat tells me that #sform doesn't exist when the script is run. Either wrap in a $(document).ready or move script below #sform

Comment: #sForm is in the main view. Should it be also in the Edit view?
I have at the bottom of the Client view
<div id="editor" style ="visibility :hidden ">
      @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sform", title = "Client Info" }))
     { 
        @Html.Partial("_ClientForm", Model)   
      }      
</div>

Comment: I also added more content as what I have right now. I have a main view where I defined the #sForm (in the invisible div). In the Edit button I  try to return a view. If I return a view containing #sForm, it doesn't seem to work at all. But I am thinking - may be I just need to wrap it in the form statement (but without id)?

Comment: Ok, I made partial success. I am now able to show the dialog correctly with the Edit and the little close button in the corner works. However, when the dialog closes, I seem to return to the original page, the grid doubles itself and the aa I put in the search box is gone.

Comment: You're getting there then. Sounds like my answer has put you on the right track

Comment: It did, but now I am facing a different problem. Now after I close that Edit dialog, the first view seems to revert to original (the text is the same as when I invoke it initially) and the grid shows doubled.
I added pictures of what I see now in this thread on jquery forum https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-can-i-define-dialog-once-and-use-it-in-add-and-edit-methods#14737000003745909

Comment: I just found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516674/how-to-use-a-jquery-ui-modal-form-from-asp-net-mvc-list-page?rq=1
 which sounds exactly like I want to implement. My question is - what is data in this case? In other words, is there a way to return just the model data (as JSON if needed) instead of returning the whole view which seems to mess up my first page? I wish I have a way to add comments in existing threads